# Select a specific tab in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

I'm trying to use the Ionic 2 and I'm still struggling with most basic tasks, such as select a tab when the app is loading.

I've tried to inject the `Tabs` controller and call `select` on the `onPageLoaded` event, but to no avail.

Can someone help maybe?

Comment: You need to call `select()` in constructor of a page where the tabs control is defined. Unfortunately I don't have an example at hand on how to get reference to the control.

Comment: Can elaborate on this some more please?

Answer (score 9):

To default to a tab in ionic 2 change the selectedIndex property:

```
<ion-tabs [selectedIndex]="1">
      <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="rewind"></ion-tab> <!-- Index 0-->
      <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="About" tabIcon="md-time"></ion-tab><!-- Index 1 (Selected)-->
      <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Contacts" tabIcon="fastforward"></ion-tab><!-- Index 2-->
</ion-tabs>
```

The About tab will be the selected tab when the page loads.

Answer (score 6):

```
//importing tabs for manipuling our ion-tabs
import {Tabs} from 'ionic-angular';
@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/page1/page1.html'
})
export class Page1 
{
    //provide Angular with metadata about things it should inject in the constructor
    static get parameters()
    {
        return [[Tabs]];
    }
    //after injecting ,passing an instance of [Tabs] in the page constructor 
    constructor(tab) {
        this.tab = tab;   
    }
    //"onPageWillEnter" function fires every time a page becomes the active      view.
    onPageWillEnter()
    {
        //make the second tab selected From the first tab (within the current Page 'page1')
        // 1 IS the index of the target tab
        this.tab.select(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take a look on this link https://webcake.co/page-lifecycle-hooks-in-ionic-2/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider explaining your code as part of your answer.

Comment: Thaks @RichardErickson ,Is that enough explained ? :p

Comment: @soufienkarray any ideas how to deselect all tabs?

Comment: Any idea how to do this on the AppComponent page? It doesn't seem to have a reference to the tabs object

Answer (score 6):

try

```
var t: Tabs = this.nav.parent;
t.select(index);
```

Answer (score 3):

In Ionic 3 and angular 4.

```
import { Tabs } from 'ionic-angular/navigation/nav-interfaces';
@ViewChild('myTabs') tabRef: Tabs; - With in the class about constructor.
this.tabRef.select(0, {}); // In the method where you want set tab.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to do it in 2022 (Ionic 5)

```
    <ion-tabs #tabs>
      <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
        <ion-tab-button tab="map">
          <ion-icon name="map"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Map</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>
         ...
     </ion-tab-bar>
   <ion-tabs>
```

Then in your typescript

```
import { IonTabs } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-some-component',
  templateUrl: './some-component.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some-component.page.scss'],
})
export class SomeComponentPage implements OnInit {
   @ViewChild('tabs') tabs: IonTabs;


  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tabs.select('pre-operative-preparation')
  }

}
```