# Navigate from Landing to a specific Tab dynamic in Ionic 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, tabs

The application opens to a landing page, named `IntroPage`, which has two buttons on it, `BUY` and `SELL`. When one of these buttons is clicked, it either takes you to the buy or sell Tab.

I have tried three different techniques, based on research from different sources such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34675922/select-a-specific-tab-in-ionic-2), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162308/ionic-2-passing-tabs-navparams-to-tab?rq=1), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903456/changing-tabs-dynamically-in-ionic-2?rq=1). For instance:

**A:**

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
```

**B:**

```
this.navCtrl.parent.select(2);
```

**C:**

```
  selectTab(index: number) {
      var t: Tabs = this.navCtrl.parent;
      t.select(index);
  }
```

My current setup:

**INTRO**

```
<button ion-button color="light" (click)="selectTab(0)">Buy</button>
<button ion-button color="light" (click)="selectTab(1)">Sell</button>

export class IntroPage {    

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public authData: AuthData,
    private zone:NgZone,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
  }

  selectTab(index: number) {
      var t: Tabs = this.navCtrl.parent;
      t.select(index);
  }

}
```

**TABS**

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" ></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" ></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab5Root" ></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab5Root" ></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>

export class TabsPage {
  tab1Root = BuyPage;
  tab2Root = SellPage;
  tab3Root = ExamplePage2;
  tab4Root = ExamplePage3;
  tab5Root = ExamplePage4;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public authData: AuthData) {
    this.onAuthCallback = this.onAuthCallback.bind(this);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `TabsPage` template add `selectedIndex` attr to `ion-tabs` tag. like this

```
<ion-tabs [selectedIndex]="tabIndex">
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" ></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" ></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab5Root" ></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab5Root" ></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

declare `tabIndex` variable in your component file, set it's value dynamically through `navParams` while using `setRoot` function.

```
export class TabsPage {
  tab1Root = BuyPage;
  ...
  tabIndex:string = 1;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,params: NavParams,public authData: AuthData) {
    this.tabIndex = this.params.get('tabIndex');
    this.onAuthCallback = this.onAuthCallback.bind(this);
  }

}
```

Then pass this `tabIndex` from any other page with index of tab you wanted to navigate.
For an instance, change your `selectTab` function like this,

```
selectTab(index: number) {
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage,{tabIndex:'1'})
  }
```